# 'chcp.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I created a new java project using "Java: Create new Project" in VSCode but whenever I run anything it always returns "'chcp.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." It also returns what I asked it to do such as print out hello world. I installed IntelliJ to see if the problem still occurred with that IDE too but there was no problem running it on IntelliJ. I added the location of chcp.com to my user and system path but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What command are you using to run the program? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-run-a-java-program

Comment: I am using Run Java in vscode. It's located in the top right of the screen

Comment: I’ll have to let someone familiar with VSCode answer, but it sounds like it’s trying to treat the `.java` file as an executable, which isn’t how it works. They’re supposed to be compiled and then ran (see link above). Sounds like IntelliJ is doing this right.

Comment: Can you share the error screenshot? Open a new integrated terminal and run `javac filename.java`  `java filename`, does the error still exists?